# How to cache image on webview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiwebview, fgallery

I have a UIWebView in UIViewController. I'm loading content for UIWebView via this function:

```
 - (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)html {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
}
```

If my content contains many images, I create a gallery via FGallery (https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone). When I open UIViewController at first time, I'm loading images and text in my UIWebView. I close an application and turn off network. Then I open my app and open a UIViewController. I'm loading my UIWebView from cache. But I have a problem. If I opened gallery until turn off network, cover of gallery doesn't load from cache, but all images from gallery are loaded. If I didn't open gallery until turn off network, cover of gallery are loaded from cache. Cover of gallery and first image of gallery are the same.

Why cover of gallery doesn't load if I opened a gallery?

Answer (score 1):

May be suitable answer of the webview

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webViewRef shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) 
    {
        NSURL *URL = [request URL]; //Get the URL
        if ( [[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"objc"] ) {
            webView = webViewRef;
            SEL method = NSSelectorFromString( [URL host] );
            if ([self respondsToSelector:method])
            {
                [self performSelector:method withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
            }
            return NO;
        }
    }
   return YES;
}
-(void)takePicture
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[delegate viewController] presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
    [imagePicker release];
}

#pragma mark - Image Picker

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    NSData *flatImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1f);
    NSString *image64 = [flatImage base64EncodedString];
    NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"processImage('data:image/jpeg;base64,%@')", image64];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    //cancel was hit inside of the camera view
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```